# can't recognize onItemClickListener in vertical and horizontal listview adapter

Tags: onitemclicklistener

I made vertical listview that contains horizontal listview in each row and I want to implement the event that when I clicked one item, I can add new item at the end of the row.

For that I try to manage the item by ArrayList> and I added setOnItemClickListener in the getView method of vertical adapter. and It doesn't work! Actually It rarely works... (when I clicked about 20 times, It works once.)

I tried unclickable and unfocusable properties in xml layout but doesn't work.

please hlp me... Here is my code

in MainActivity
I used VerticalAdapter like this. I set totallist as the parameter of VerticalAdpater

```
verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.schedule_routine, TotalList);
listview.setAdapter(verListAdapter);
```

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;

    this.aposition = position;

    rowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.part_list_item, null);
    hListView = (HorizontialListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.hlistview);
    tv_info = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_infoitem);
    tv_info.setText(Integer.toString(position));

    hListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int iposition, long id) {
            tv_info.setText("hello");

            PartContent temp_part = new PartContent("part", R.drawable.plus);
            PartContent temp_base_part = new PartContent("part", R.drawable.dumb);

            if(iposition == (totallist.get(aposition).size()) - 1) {                                
                tv_info.setText(Integer.toString(iposition));
                totallist.get(aposition).set(iposition, temp_base_part);
                totallist.get(aposition).add(temp_part);
            }

            HorizontialAdapter hortempAdapter = new HorizontialAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.part_item, getItem(iposition));
            hListView.setAdapter(hortempAdapter);
            hortempAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }});

    HorizontialAdapter horListAdapter = new HorizontialAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.part_item, totallist.get(position));
    hListView.setAdapter(horListAdapter);

    return rowView;
}
```